# Problem with Arch Linux installation (zoneinfo)

Tags: arch-linux, system-installation, timezone

I'm installing Arch Linux thru a USB device.
I have already downloaded the files into the root directory and now I was trying to set up my timezone for the clock.
I went to `cd /usr/share/zoneinfo` and it displayed some country options for me to choose, but when I tried to access mine (Portugal), it says that it's not a directory.

This is how I try to access it: `cd /usr/share/zoneinfo/Portugal`

I tried with other countries for example Canada and it works on the others, not on Portugal. What should I do? What am I doing wrong and how do I fix this?

Comment: what is the output of `ls -l /usr/share/zoneinfo/  | grep Portugal`

Comment: @Hunter.S.Thompson it says: -rw-r--r-- 2 root root  3453 Mar 24 2017 Portugal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To set the `timezone` to Portugal do :

```
timedatectl set-timezone Portugal
```

This command will create an `/etc/localtime` `symlink` that points to a `zoneinfo` file under `/usr/share/zoneinfo/`.

If you want to create the `symlink` manually do :

```
ln -sf /usr/share/zoneinfo/Portugal /etc/localtime
```

### Why cant I `cd` into it.

It is because it is a file.

### Why is it a file?

It is a file because the time difference between each city in Portugal is not that much compared to cities in bigger countries like the **U.S** and/or **Canada**, which would have Subzones in the folder, but Portugal has no Subzones, therefore it is only a file and not a directory.

Comment: timedatectl set-timezone Portugal give me an error:  "Failed to create bus connection: No such file or directory"

Comment: Try the command that manually creates the link to the file.

Answer (score 0):

To **list** all available time zones, you have two options:

1. **Manually** list the contents of the `/usr/share/zoneinfo` directory.
2. Use the `timedatectl list-timezones` command. This command will give you a list of results in the **Region/City** format. The one you are looking for is **Europe/Lisbon**.

Finally you have two ways of **setting up the time zone**:

1. **Manually**, creating a symbolic link: `ln -sf /usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/Lisbon /etc/localtime`
2. Use the `timedatectl` command again: `sudo timedatectl set-timezone Europe/Lisbon`